# What is the difference between だろう and でしょう?

Tags: grammar

Basically, the title says it all.

I've encountered quite a handful of sentences with these words, of which meanings seems to be the same. I'm just wondering in what ways they differ and how people use them...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most accurate (literal) translation of でしょう?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12670/what-is-the-most-accurate-literal-translation-of-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86)

Answer (score 4):

でしょう？ is the polite form of だろう？  but the main difference is that, while men can use でしょう？, women rarely use だろう？ because of how masculine it is(Unless they're young women speaking to their friends.)

For example, if you hear that the person you like is going to marry someone else. You reply with　嘘だろう？

In the case of a girl, she would maybe say うそでしょう？

Sorry for my crappy examples haha.